# iOS 11 simulator dyld: Symbol not found: _CKAccountChangedNotification

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, ios11

Does anyone know what happened for my iOS 11 simulator? When i launch on iOS 11, the app can't work, and says in console:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _CKAccountChangedNotification

Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuet.framework/CoreDuet

Expected in: /Users/steve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cloud-bvzzwfgkjzfnzibxrwadbayiowcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CloudKit.framework/CloudKit in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuet.framework/CoreDuet"
```

But everything is fine when run in iOS 10 simulator or on the device with iOS 11. How can i fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have a framework called "CloudKit.framework" in your build products directory?

Comment: "CloudKit.framework" is just a custom framework to share codes between  host app and its extensions, "Cloud" is the app name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudKit is a system framework so your framework is interfering with other system frameworks trying to find the symbol in the real `CloudKit.framework`

This happens because the Simulator does not currently use a dyld shared cache (otherwise the symbols would already have been resolved to the system-provided `CloudKit.framework`) *and* Xcode sets up the `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH` to point to the built products directory so it can find your frameworks even though they aren't packaged up in their final install location.

These two combined causes dyld to see your version of `CloudKit.framework` when it attempts to resolve `_CKAccountChangedNotification`.

The solution is to rename your framework.